# Phone numer verification

Tags: android, firebase, sms, verification

I am writing an android application in Java and I would like to secure it with phone number verification. I use firebase as a database and there is phone number authentication but that's not what I need. I need a solution where the user will provide his phone number to which the SMS code will come. The application will check whether the entered code is the same as the one sent and, depending on the result, an appropriate message will be displayed. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What is your question for us? And (given that you say you don't want to use Firebase Authentication) how does it relate to Firebase?

Comment: How to verify the user's phone number? In firebase, I would like to store information whether the user has verified the phone number.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to build your own phone number verification flow outside of Firebase Authentication and write the verification result in Firestore? That's certainly possible, but is a really broad use-case - so in order for us to help it's probably better if you focus on a specific subset of the problem, e.g. what is the current step in this use-case you are implementing, and where are you stuck?